# lua script :need help to understand the scope of an variable

Tags: lua, closures, scope

I have a following code and I want to understand the scope of the variable inside that adder function. How it could able to retain the `x` value on call?

```
function adder(x)
    return function (y) return x + y end
end

a1 = adder(9)

a2 = adder(36)

print(a1(33)) --  42 how this can able to retain the value of x

print(a2(64)) --  100
```

I am getting `42` ,when I called that adder function second time. how this is possible  here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is called **lexical scoping**, or it's a **closure**. It means that functions can access variables of their enclosing functions.

```
function adder(x)
    return function (y) return x + y end
end
```

The anonymous function has full access to local variable `x` in the enclosing function `adder`. `x` is called a non-global variable (or upvalue for historical reasons) inside the anonymous function, because it's neither a global variable nor a local variable to the anonymous function.

For detail, read the chapter [*More about Functions* in Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.html).

Comment: "print(a1(33))"  does this called that anonymous function directly?.

Comment: @user2793492 Yes, the anonymous function (with the value of variable `x`) is stored in the variable `a1` now.

Comment: As per my understanding "a1 = adder(9)" -- this time we are passing 9 as a arg to that function adder(x)
But on this call 
print(a1(33)) :: 33 also belongs to x right .. but i was getting X+y . can you explain this please?

Comment: @user2793492 Not really. In the call to `a1(33)`, `33` is passed as the value of `y`, as that the argument of `a1`.

Comment: but we are assigning a1 ["a1 = adder(9)"] to adder function right? is this related to this syntax below  like ... we can write a1=function (y) return x+y ..as function a1 (y) return x+y.. so that  anonymous function got that value of y as 33 ..and [x has a scope inside that  anonymous function] so it will return x+y ...is that so

Comment: @Bee.. I'm not following you, why not read the PiL book, it has a simpler example of closure, start form understanding it.